# laravel livewire mount dynamic fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I would like to have dynamic input fields with values ​​for all that are already entered in the db.

the following code works!
here the values ​​of the input extras.4 fields are displayed on the website

```
public function mount() {

        $this->advettisment_extras = DB::table('advertisment_extras')
            ->where('advertisment_number', '=', $this->advertisment['advertisment_number'])
            ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get()->toArray();

        foreach ($this->advettisment_extras as $advettisment_extra) {
            $this->extras = [
                '4' => '12346548'
            ];
        }
    }
```

but when I try to dynamically search for and fill in the fields from db, the values ​​are not displayed.

```
        foreach ($this->advettisment_extras as $advettisment_extra) {
            $this->extras = [
                $advettisment_extra->extra_id => $advettisment_extra->extra_value
            ];
        }
```

can anyone help ?

Comment: Please share your rendered blade as well.

Comment: I don't understand the content inside of the foreach loop. You are overwriting $this->extras in each iteration. Is this the real code you are using? And as Digvijay said - show the blade code too. I can't understand how you get 4 inputs from $extras there. All I can see is $extras having one item only ['4' => '12345664']

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row" wire:init="loadExtras">
    @if(isset($categorie_extras))
        @foreach($categorie_extras as $categorie_extra)
            <div class="col-4 form-group">{!! getExtraField($categorie_extra->extra_id, $advertisment->advertisment_number) !!}</div>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</div>
```

and my getExtraField Function in helper.php

```
//Helper für Anzeige der Extra Felder
function getExtraField($extra_id, $advertisment_number) {
    $field = '';
    $option = '';
    // Extra aus DB holen
    $extra = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('extras')->where('id', '=', $extra_id)->first();
    $advertisment_extras = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('advertisment_extras')
        ->where('advertisment_number', '=', $advertisment_number)
        ->where('user_id', '=', \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->id)->get();

    switch ($extra->extra_form_item) {

        case 'input':

            foreach($advertisment_extras as $advertisment_extra) {
                if ($advertisment_extra->extra_id == $extra->id ) {
                    $field = '<label for="' . $extra->id . '">' . $extra->extra_field_label . '</label><input type="' . $extra->extra_input_field_type . '" wire:model.lazy="extras.' . $extra->id . '" name="' . $extra->id . '" class="form-control" id="' . $extra->id . '">';
                    break;
                } else {
                    $field = '<label for="' . $extra->id . '">' . $extra->extra_field_label . '</label><input type="' . $extra->extra_input_field_type . '" wire:model.lazy="extras.' . $extra->id . '" name="' . $extra->id . '" class="form-control" id="' . $extra->id . '">';
                }
            }
            break;

        case 'select':
            $values = explode(',', $extra->extra_enum_select_values);
            // Option des Select Feldes suchen
            $field_1 = '<label for="' . $extra->id . '">' . $extra->extra_field_label  . '</label><select name="' . $extra->id . '" wire:model="extras.'. $extra->id . '" class="form-control"  id="' . $extra->id .  '">';
            foreach ($values as $value) {
                $option = $option .'<option value="'. $value . '">' . $value . '</option>';
            }
            $field_3 = '</select>';

            $field = $field_1 . $option . $field_3;
            break;

        case 'checkbox' :
            $field = '<label for="' . $extra->id . '">' . $extra->extra_field_label  . '</label><br><input type="checkbox" name="' . $extra->id . '" wire:model="extras.'. $extra->id . '" class="" value="1"  id="' . $extra->id .  '">';
            break;
    }

     return $field;
}
```

and my complete component:

```
//Helper für Anzeige der Extra Felder
function getExtraField($extra_id, $advertisment_number) {
    $field = '';
    $option = '';
    // Extra aus DB holen
    $extra = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('extras')->where('id', '=', $extra_id)->first();
    $advertisment_extras = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('advertisment_extras')
        ->where('advertisment_number', '=', $advertisment_number)
        ->where('user_id', '=', \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->id)->get();

    switch ($extra->extra_form_item) {

        case 'input':

            foreach($advertisment_extras as $advertisment_extra) {
                if ($advertisment_extra->extra_id == $extra->id ) {
                    $field = '<label for="' . $extra->id . '">' . $extra->extra_field_label . '</label><input type="' . $extra->extra_input_field_type . '" wire:model.lazy="extras.' . $extra->id . '" name="' . $extra->id . '" class="form-control" id="' . $extra->id . '">';
                    break;
                } else {
                    $field = '<label for="' . $extra->id . '">' . $extra->extra_field_label . '</label><input type="' . $extra->extra_input_field_type . '" wire:model.lazy="extras.' . $extra->id . '" name="' . $extra->id . '" class="form-control" id="' . $extra->id . '">';
                }
            }
            break;

        case 'select':
            $values = explode(',', $extra->extra_enum_select_values);
            // Option des Select Feldes suchen
            $field_1 = '<label for="' . $extra->id . '">' . $extra->extra_field_label  . '</label><select name="' . $extra->id . '" wire:model="extras.'. $extra->id . '" class="form-control"  id="' . $extra->id .  '">';
            foreach ($values as $value) {
                $option = $option .'<option value="'. $value . '">' . $value . '</option>';
            }
            $field_3 = '</select>';

            $field = $field_1 . $option . $field_3;
            break;

        case 'checkbox' :
            $field = '<label for="' . $extra->id . '">' . $extra->extra_field_label  . '</label><br><input type="checkbox" name="' . $extra->id . '" wire:model="extras.'. $extra->id . '" class="" value="1"  id="' . $extra->id .  '">';
            break;
    }

     return $field;
}
```

my problem is that the value is not displayed in the fontend. That means the mount function does not work dynamically, but if I put it in directly as described above it works:

```
        foreach ($xs as $x) {
            $this->extras = [
                '4' => '12345678'
            ];
        }
```

but I would like to load the fields dynamically with values ​​like here:

```
        foreach ($xs as $x) {
            $this->extras = [
                $x->extra_id => $x->extra_value,
            ];
        }
```

Thanks for help :)